# detecting the session while closing the browser on php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to capture the records when the users is actually logged into the portal and  when he exits the portal, if he was logged out to the system properly I can catch it easily, and the get the record out there, but if the user closed the browser session will end but i cant catch the details when it ends, i gone research about it found some jquery solutions as

```
 $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
      return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
});
```

and

```
$(window).unload(function() {
       return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
});
```

both the above solutions working only on IE browser not in chrome, firefox etc, that too not detecting the onclose event alone i was detecting the browser refresh if i try to navigate to some other page it retruns the function, is there any better solution to achieve this?

Comment: Best way is to update the `user` record in the data with a field `last_activity (datetime)`, then compare this field with something like `NOW() - 1800` to determine when someone is not online anymore

Comment: Yeah use a heartbeat, use websockets or poll the server every 30 seconds, which keep a column updated, then for users which have old timestamps their are offline.

Comment: this is an internet radio station, we can't expect users last_activity because they be idle and listen to the music alone @DarkBee

Comment: @LawrenceCherone good idea, thanxx, will try with this

Answer (score 0):

`beforeunload` event can be used to trigger an action before the user leaves the page. This event for extensive server-side actions or capturing records might not be entirely reliable due to browser restrictions

Here's an example using jQuery to make an AJAX request to a server-side script.

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
    // Make an AJAX request to capture the record on the server
    $.ajax({
        url: 'capture_record.php',  // Replace with your server-side script
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'logout',  // You can send additional data if needed
        },
        async: false,  // Synchronous request to give it time to execute before leaving
    });
    
    // Your confirmation message (some browsers may not show this message)
    return "Do you really want to close?";
});

<?php
// capture_record.php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['action'] === 'logout') {
        // Capture the record in the database or perform other actions
        // Example: Insert a logout record into a database
        // $userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        // $timestamp = time();
        // Write a Query for DB Record with parameter ($userId, $timestamp);

        // Respond to the AJAX request
        echo 'Record captured successfully';
        exit;
    }
}

// Handle other actions or respond accordingly
?>
```